# Как сделать свои сообщения об ошибках в Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii

Rак можно сделать свои сообщения об ошибках в Yii 2?

Например, в

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

в случае неправомерного доступа выдает следующую ошибку:

```
You are not allowed to perform this action.
```

А можно ли их менять на свои:

```
Вы не имеете доступа к данной странице
```

?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html 
 Советую прочитать это статью, там все описано